how to fixed ubuntu server 20.04 LTS /dev/mapper/ubuntu/--vg-ubuntu--lv contains a file system with errors, check forced
I am newbie for Linux Ubuntu Server 20.04 LTS user.
I have a cases with my Linux Ubuntu PC Server.
When I boot my PC, I got an error with:
/dev/mapper/ubuntu/--vg-ubuntu--lv contains a file system with errors, check forced
someone please help me to guide me for trouble shooting in my cases step by step in linux command.
Warm Regards,
